# Error DriverManager para conectar a mysql JAVA

Tags: java

Quiero realizar una conexion a una base de datos que ya cree en mysql pero no me toma la variable **DriverManager**.

```java
public class Conexion {
    
    Connection con;
    String user="root";
    String password2="";
    String url="jdbc:mysql://3306/p";
    
    public Connection Conectar(){
        
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password2);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conexion c=new Conexion();
        Connection con;
        con=c.Conectar();
    }
    
}
```

Tambien he importado lo que necesitan las variables y aun asi tengo error en **DriverManager**.

Comment: Pusiste el puerto, pero no pusiste de dónde es ese puerto, te faltó poner localhost

Comment: `String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/p"`

Comment: ¿qué quiere decir exactamente "no me toma la variable DriverManager" o "he importado lo que necesitan las variables" ¿Puedes poner qué has importado?. ¿Qué error tienes exactamente?